# How to increase the speed of building android project in eclipse?

Tags: android, debugging, compilation

Hello I have Eclipse SDK Version: 3.6.2. I am developing the application which contains many XML file for all Phone,Tablet (small,normal,large,xlarge folder) .

When i compile the projects it takes too much time to compile.

Please give any suggestion for this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is *too much time*? What would be acceptable? What's your hardware like?

Comment: I think its because of your Hardware configuration.

Comment: It depends on the hardware, but also it depends on the Android SDK version. Recent version have added a lot of optimization for compilation and build time. Please update your question with details, eg. how many resources does your project have, what is the hardware setup, what is the Android SDK version, and lastly how much time does the compilation take and what would be acceptible for you.

Comment: My PC Configuration is Intel Code I3,2.93 GHz, 4GB RAM

Comment: 4GB RAM with i3 is more than enough for good speed. It looks like you have an old version of android sdk. I have _android-sdk_r20-windows_ installed and it is giving good speed for building workspace.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have mark the skip packing or dexing until export or launch, this will help you build the project faster atleast when you are saving or building, It will take when launching as packaging will be done during the launch.

[image]